# Access to PFQueryTableViewController activity indicator?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController, and I'd like to access its activity indicator to pause my UI from updating until it's finished.  Is there a bool value I can access to get a reference to it? (I understand that I can do this using a plain UITableView but for this particular use I am using a PFQTVC)

edit:  Im in Swift

Comment: Override objectsDidLoad which is called after the query completes.